# PHP WS-Security with certificate and sign

Tags: php, xml, soap, ws-security

I have to make a SOAP Request with WS-Security using PHP.
After some reserch, i found this library: https://github.com/robrichards/wse-php and with that i'm able to add security header to my soap, but the result it's quite different from what i need.

I'm new to soap and ws-security so i'm trying to understand what is the right library i have to use. At the moment i have no idea if this one suits for my needs....but i don't have found the right solution.

This is the code:

```
require 'xmlseclibs-master/src/XMLSecurityKey.php';
require 'xmlseclibs-master/src/XMLSecurityDSig.php';
require 'xmlseclibs-master/src/XMLSecEnc.php';
require 'xmlseclibs-master/src/Utils/XPath.php';
require 'wse-php-master/src/WSSESoap.php';
require 'wse-php-master/src/WSASoap.php';

use RobRichards\WsePhp\WSASoap;
use RobRichards\WsePhp\WSSESoap;
use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityKey;

class mySoap extends SoapClient {

    private $cert = 'header.p7b';
    private $key = 'header.key';

    function __doRequest($request, $location, $saction, $version, $one_way = null) {
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML($request);

        $objWSA = new WSASoap($dom);
        $objWSA->addAction($saction);
        $objWSA->addTo($location);
        $objWSA->addMessageID();
        $objWSA->addReplyTo();

        $dom = $objWSA->getDoc();

        $objWSSE = new WSSESoap($dom);
        /* Sign all headers to include signing the WS-Addressing headers */
        $objWSSE->signAllHeaders = TRUE;

        $objWSSE->addTimestamp(3600);
        
        /* create new XMLSec Key using RSA SHA-1 and type is private key */
        $objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA1, array('type'=>'private'));

        /* load the private key from file - last arg is bool if key in file (TRUE) or is string (FALSE) */
        $objKey->loadKey($this->key, TRUE);

        /* Sign the message - also signs appropraite WS-Security items */
        $objWSSE->signSoapDoc($objKey);

        /* Add certificate (BinarySecurityToken) to the message and attach pointer to Signature */
        $token = $objWSSE->addBinaryToken(file_get_contents($this->cert));
        $objWSSE->attachTokentoSig($token);
        
        $request = $objWSSE->saveXML();
        $f = fopen('debug.txt','w');
        fwrite($f,print_r($request,true));
        fclose($f);
        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $saction, $version);
    }
}
$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'local_cert'        => 'file.pem',
        'local_pk'        => 'file.key',
        #'passphrase'        => 'password',
        'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
        'ciphers' => 'SHA256',
        'verify_peer'=>false,
        'verify_peer_name'=>false, 
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$soap = new mySoap('<wsdl>',array(
        'soap_version'      => SOAP_1_1,
        'location'          => '<location>',
        'trace'             => 1,
        'exceptions'        => 0,
        'stream_context'    => stream_context_create($opts)
    ));
$array = array(
    "param1" => 'param1', 
    "param2" => 'param2', 
    "param3" => 'param3',
);
try {
    $out = $soap->method($array);
    var_dump($out);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    var_dump($fault);
}
```

This is the result i have to achive:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="##ENV_URL##">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="##WSSE##" xmlns:wsu="##WSU_URL###" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="##TOKEN_ENC##" ValueType="##TOKEN_VAL_TYPE##" wsu:Id="##TOKEN_ID##">##TOKEN_VAL##</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="##URI1##">
                <wsu:Created>##DATE1##</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>##DATE2##</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="##ALG1_URL##" Id="##ALG1_ID##">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="##ALG4_URL##"/>
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="##KEY1_DS##">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                                <ds:X509IssuerName>##ISSUER_NAME##</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                <ds:X509SerialNumber>##ISSUER_SERIAL##</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                            </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>##CIPHER1_VALUE##</xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:ReferenceList>
                    <xenc:DataReference URI="##ALG1_ID##"/>
                </xenc:ReferenceList>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="##KEY1_DS##" Id="##SIGN_ID##">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="##ALG2_URL##">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="##ALG2_URL##" PrefixList="soap"/>
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="##ALG4_URL##"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="##URI1##">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="##ALG2_URL##">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="##ALG2_URL##" PrefixList="soap wsse"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="##ALG5_URL##"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>##DIG1_VALUE##</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="##WSU_BODY_ID##">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="##ALG2_URL##"/>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="##ALG5_URL##"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>##DIG1_VALUE##</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="###TOKEN_ID##">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="##ALG2_URL##">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="##ALG2_URL##" PrefixList="soap"/>
                        </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="##ALG5_URL##"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>##DIG2_VALUE##</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>##SIGN_VALUE##</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="##KEY_ID##">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="##WSSE##" xmlns:wsu="##WSU_URL###" wsu:Id="##WSU_KEY_ID##">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="###TOKEN_ID##" ValueType="##TOKEN_VAL_TYPE##"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body xmlns:wsu="##WSU_URL###" wsu:Id="##WSU_BODY_ID##">
        <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="##ALG1_URL##" Id="##ALG1_ID##" Type="##ALG1_URL##Content">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="##ALG6_URL##"/>
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="##KEY1_DS##">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="##WSSE##" xmlns:wsse11="##WSSE11##" wsse11:TokenType="##WSSE11_TOKEN##">
                    <wsse:Reference URI="##ALG1_ID##"/>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:CipherValue>##CYPHER2_VALUE##</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: We built an integration many years ago that required WS-Sec and it was "fun". We didn't use that library (it either didn't work for us or didn't exist, I can't remember) but we did use [another](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs) from the same person for signing. We ultimately ended up building our own XML document to match the required spec and then used that library to handle signing. Make sure to watch your canonicalization rules as well as signature hash algorithms.

Comment: Where did you start from to build your own XML document? For example, i don't know what to search to build the <EncryptedData> or the <Signature>. Everything i try to search on the web isn't equals to what i need...i'm kinda lost eheh

Comment: For us, the actual implementation was WS Federation which is a subset of WS SEC, and our use-case was for SSO. We were able to use our own XML because 90% of it was just boilerplate stuff. Make sure you have a good working knowledge of XML namespaces, btw, and what they actually do. The signature part of the document is [handled here](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs/blob/master/src/XMLSecurityDSig.php), and the library you referenced uses that internally. See this for [EncryptedData](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs/blob/master/tests/xmlsec-encrypt-noreplace.phpt)

Comment: Can you give me some advice for the BinarySecurityToken and the Encrypted Body too? Thank you again fro your time.

Comment: I unfortunately can't spend too much more time on this, but I set up a quick [proof-of-concept](https://github.com/vendi-advertising/so-64607833) that points to a [live SOAP endpoint](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl). The keys I'm using come right from [XmlSecLibs](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs/tree/master/tests). This does **not** have the encryption part, I'm not as familiar with that part, so hopefully you can add that. You should be able to run `composer install` and then `php test.php` (or through a browser, probably, too).